# Find dynamically added elem.firstChild

Tags: javascript, dynamic-arrays, event-listener

I've got some code for dynamically added tabs with content. When removing a tab, eventListener launches a callback function which takes an array of tab + content as parameters.

**[newTab]** - array of dynamically created tabs

**[newContent]** - array of dynamically created divs (tabs content)
Here's the code for that:

```
    tabSpan.addEventListener("click", removeTab([newTab, newContent]));
```

The thing is when I remove a tab with class *active* I need to pass this class to the first tab in array if it exists, if not - do nothing.
The issue I am trying to solve is that my **removeTab** function doesn't get the first child of **newTab** array.

```
    //Remove tab
    function removeTab(nodeArr) {
    return function() {


        nodeArr.forEach(function(el) {

           el.parentNode && el.parentNode.removeChild(el);

        });

        console.log(tabs.closest("li.item"));
    };
 }
```

**console.log** displays *null*

How can I retrieve that **firstChild** in my case to pass class *active* to it?

HTML (do not pay attention to the *defaultTab*, it doesn't count as *firstChild* in this case):

```
<div class="wrap">

    <ul id="tabs">

        <li id="defaultTab" class="tab default">
                <span>+</span>
        </li>


    </ul><!--Tabs ul End-->

    <div id="defaultDiv" class="content default">

    </div>
```

[JS Bin DEMO](https://jsbin.com/nugilibome/edit?js,output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It display null because closest is looking for it's parent, not children.

### What is closest() method?

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

> The Element.closest() method returns the closest ancestor of the
>   current element (or the current element itself) which matches the
>   selectors given in parameter.

### What is ancestor?

According to [W3school](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_closest.asp)

> An ancestor is a parent, grandparent, great-grandparent, and so on.

So we should look for child element. We can use querySelector() here.

### What is querySelector?

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector)

> Returns the first element within the document

Also we have to avoid javascript is loading before DOM and can use setTimeout here. So final code is

```
setTimeout(function waitDom() {
    tabs.querySelector("*").classList.add("active");
    defaultDiv.querySelector("*").classList.add("active");
   }, 0);
};
```

#### [Here](http://codepen.io/cmlonder/pen/KzBqqd) is the working fiddler.